# Remove brackets and quotation marks from CSV generated output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I use [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to save each line in a text file as a separate object in the database.

Each line is saved with added closing brackets and double quotes:

```
["One line of text"]
```

Is there any option in CSV to exclude those, or else any other nifty way to remove them?

Comment: Could you be converting an array into a string?  Maybe post a little more of your input file and code to convert to csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'csv'

def self.import_lines_of_text(filename)
  csv_file_path = "db/questions/#{filename}"

  CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|
    clean_sentence = row.join(",")
    self.create!(content: clean_sentence)
  end
end
```